# Google Chart Sorting vs Google Chart Editor

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Please help! I am about to go insane over this! I have a Javascript for Google Chart that builds a table and a chart on the same dataset and when you sort the table the values on the chart get sorted as well. I also have a code that opens up the Google Charts Editor... which builds it's own chart. What I need is to merge these two functions. I need to build a table and a chart (that will get sorted as I sort the table) and when I open the Editor I need it to edit THAT chart (which will still be linked with sorting in the table) and NOT build a NEW chart.

Here are the 2 functions I have:

```
function drawSort() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable( <?= $jsonTable ?> );

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        prefix: '$'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_s_div'));
    table.draw(view);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_s_div'));
    chart.draw(view);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',

    function (event) {
        data.sort([{
            column: event.column,
            desc: !event.ascending
        }]);
        chart.draw(view);
    });
}

var chartEditor = null;

function loadEditor() {
    // Create the chart to edit.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable( <?= $jsonTable ?> );
    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            'title': 'Number of Newly Opened Roles per <?echo $_SESSION['
            Display ']?>',
                'legend': 'none',
        }
    });

    chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
    chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {})
}

// On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
function redrawChart() {
    chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_s_div'));
}
```